# react native modal not open when screen load

Tags: react-native, react-component

i want to open modal when screen load so i am change state when component did mount my code is:

**state:**

```
this.state = {
  orientation: this.isPortrait() ? 'portrait' : 'landscape',
  isModalDate:true 
};
```

**component code:**

```
componentDidMount(){
  this._onPressAccountdata();
}
```

**Change state function:**

```
_onPressAccountdata() {
  //Alert.alert("1");
  this.setState({ isModalDate: !this.state.isModalDate  });
  console.log("modal state"+this.state.isModalDate)
}
```

**render modal**

```
<Modal
  isVisible={this.state.isModalDate}
  onSwipe={() => this.setState({ isModalDate: false })}
  swipeDirection="left"
  style={styles.modal_css}
  supportedOrientations={['portrait', 'landscape']}
>
 {...}
</Modal>
```

Modal open when button click it work perfectly but when screen load it not working what's wrong in my code

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this problem using simple tricks i change state after 1 seconds when componentDidMount.
**Code:**

```
componentDidMount() {

 this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({ isModalDate: !this.state.isModalDate  });
 }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial state includes `isModalDate:true`. Therefore, when the component mounts and it calls `_onPressAccountdata`, `isModalDate` gets flipped (as expected) and becomes false.

Try setting `isModalDate` initially to false instead.

Answer (score 0):

This happens mostly when you have a transition on your screen.
check this post:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72630020/11013068)