# React Native: Opening a Modal from inside another Modal doesn't work in iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I have a Dropdown component which is just a React Native `Modal` positioned next to a toggle - the `Modal` allows me to make the whole background a `Pressable` so I can close the dropdown when any area outside it is pressed.

The items inside the dropdown menu each have an `onPress` prop which performs a given function while also closing the dropdown itself. This works great, except when I want to use the `onPress` event to open another react-native `Modal`.

Here's a (simplified) example:

```
<>
  // Custom component that renders a react-native Modal
  <Dropdown
    items={[
      { label: "Press to open a Modal", onPress: () => setIsModalOpen(true) }
    ]}
  />

  // Another react-native Modal
  <Modal visible={isModalOpen}>
    ...
  </Modal>
</>
```

This works as expected on the web - the Dropdown's `Modal` closes and the other `Modal` opens at the same time. However, on iOS, the second `Modal` never opens, and the app actually becomes completely unresponsive until I restart it from the Metro builder.

I've seen other questions on Stack Overflow that mention "opening a modal from inside another modal", but the existing questions all seem to concern nested modals. In my case, we aren't actually trying to nest modals - the second modal should open as the first one closes. The iOS app seems to just not render the second modal, even though I can verify through the console that the `isModalOpen` boolean is getting set to true.

I'm beginning to think this is actually a bug with React Native itself, but figured I'd check here in case it's a known issue, maybe with event bubbling or something?

Comment: This’s a limitation in react native, there’s actually a workaround: using setTimout for opening 2nd modal after closing 1st open which mean that you have to close 1st modal first or wait until it got dismissed than open the 2nd one https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal#i-cant-show-multiple-modals-one-after-another

Comment: With the timeout I'm able to get the second modal to open one time, but subsequent opens fail. Can't seem to get it working consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**So at the end of the day, the issue is that React Native simply won't show two modals at the same time** - this limitation applies even if you're trying to open a new modal while the previous one's closing animation is still finishing up.

It seems like some people handle this with a timeout, but that proved unreliable in my testing. A timeout also relies on a magic number, when the crux of the issue is that the modal has yet to unmount before opening a new one.

To solve this, I added a state variable called `queuedPress` to my Dropdown menu's context provider that stores the `onPress` function from the menu item that was just pressed. I also added an `afterClose` callback that runs when the Dropdown menu's closing animation completes. When a Dropdown item is pressed, I store its `onPress` function, then `afterClose` handles the actual call. This ensures the `onPress` is queued for as long as the animation takes to complete, so the modal opened from within that `onPress` will be guaranteed to open after the dropdown is already closed.

Depending on your code your implementation might vary wildly, but in my case this is another situation where `useContext` has saved the day. Any solution that limits the number of open modals to 1 should work.

Comment: This seems like the right approach but how to you tell when the "closing animation completes"? iOS offers onDismiss, but that doesn't work on Android.

Answer (score 3):

This's [a known limitation](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal#i-cant-show-multiple-modals-one-after-another) in `react-native`

but as a **workaround**

1. you can use `setTimeout` for the 2nd modal after closing the 1st modal
2. use conditional rendering so it registers(mount/unmount) to the dom the 2nd modal based on the visibility

```js
import React, {useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Modal, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [is1stModalVisible, setIs1stModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [is2ndModalVisible, setIs2ndModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const onOpen2ndModal = useCallback(() => {
    // closes the 1st modal
    setIs1stModalVisible(false);
    // open the 2nd modal
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        setIs2ndModalVisible(true);
      },
      // any small number will do, maybe animation duration
      100,
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Open 1st modal"
        onPress={() => setIs1stModalVisible(true)}
      />

      <Modal visible={is1stModalVisible}>
        <Text>Modal 1 content</Text>
        <Button title="Open 2nd modal" onPress={onOpen2ndModal} />
      </Modal>
      {is2ndModalVisible ? (
        <Modal visible={is2ndModalVisible}>
          <Text>Modal 2 content</Text>
          <Button
            title="Close 2nd modal"
            onPress={() => setIs2ndModalVisible(false)}
          />
        </Modal>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: If I attached an event to the animation end for the first modal, would that accomplish the same thing without a timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `InteractionManager` inside your first modal `useEffect`. that guarantees your second modal will open after the first modal animation is finished.

```
InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
   // ...long-running synchronous task...
 });
```

more detail:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/interactionmanager

Comment: That's amazing, I implemented my own queue without knowing this was available. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of triggering the second modal's opening using a timeout, we could use onModalHide attribute on the first modal to trigger the opening of the second modal.

The onModalHide method is called only after the first modal is closed.

However, this does not come with standard Modal from react-native. We need to use the react-native-modal package for this feature. It only provides additional features, so should not be hard to implement.